# how do i start many threads in a queue?

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue

I'm making server-client application. Client can manage server files (rename/copy/delete etc.) When I select more than one like (n) files to copy/paste it starts (n) threads of **pasteC**

I need a way to make them in a queue. How do I do that???

```
private void Paste()
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in copiedItems)
    {
        Thread pasteC = new Thread(unused => fmc.PasteFromCopy(item.Text, somePath));
        pasteC.Start();
    }
}
```

the code down is in fmc class..

```
public void PasteFromCopy(string source,string dest)
{
    if (IsFolder(source))
    {
        CopyDirectory(source, dest);
    }
    else
    {
        CopyStream(source, dest); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does it start n threads? Copying files is usually not CPU-bound, so the threads will actually make it *slower*, not faster. And if you want to run the threads in sequence, why don't you just do that, without using any threads?

Comment: im sorry i didn't explain about my application .. its client-server .. it lets me able to control files and folders.. and explore them .. so if i didn't use threads.. it will lag and i will not be able to explore while copying files .. so i had to use threads so i can explore and rename and see size and all other stuff while it's copying ..

Comment: Then use just *one* thread, see edit to my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i've figured it out

```
public void PasteFromCopy(string source,string dest)
{
    lock(this)
    {
        if (IsFolder(source))
        {
            CopyDirectory(source, dest);
        }
        else
        {
            CopyStream(source, dest); 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not adding anything to a queue. You're simply locking this block of code.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Why are you creating all the threads when they then only wait for each other?

Comment: it's a large file copy.. suppose it's 1 giga byte for each file.. and i have 3 files.. do you want the computer to start those threads together ?? for me .. LOCK .. just worked perfect.

Comment: @MurHafSoz, no, I wouldn't use threads for this at all, it doesn't make any sense and just makes your code more complicated.

Comment: im sorry i didn't explain about my application .. its client-server .. it lets me able to control files and folder.. and explore them .. so if i didn't use threads.. it will lag and i will not be able to explore while copying files .. what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no reason to use threads here. You're just making your code more complicated and consume too much memory (each thread needs 1 MB of memory). Do something like this and you won't have to worry about queues or locks:

```
private void Paste()
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in copiedItems)
    {
        fmc.PasteFromCopy(item.Text, somePath);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you need to use thread other than the main thread, because you don't want to lock that up, you can use *one* thread that does all the copying. Something like:

```
private void Paste()
{
    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in copiedItems)
        {
            fmc.PasteFromCopy(item.Text, somePath);
        }
    });
    thread.Start();
}
```

Still no need to use locks, and much more memory efficient than your solution with many threads.

Comment: ok here's a thing .. for some reasons that i need to confirm each file and check if exists and these stuff.. i send to server a single file(path) each time to copy .. it uses one thread for that.. so the server receives paths from the client side which sends in a FOREACH LOOP .. that's means it doesnt send all of the paths in one send .. so its gonna run many threads .. that why i had to use lock .. because each file uses a thread.. i tried many time to edit my code to use the best way.. but it ends this way .. if you know what i mean.

Comment: client has listview of the current folders/files.. it check if the file/folder exists for each the copiedItems.. show confirmation message .. if yes it sends the path to server .. if no.. it skips to the other file and like that ..

Comment: No, I don't really know what you mean. It's hard to help you if you don't explain what exactly do you need and only know you've told us. Now it seems like what you actually need is actually a queue, one thread takes items from it and does the copying, another thread can add items to the queue. The easiest way to do this is to use `BlockingCollection<T>`.

Comment: so lock doesn't put them in a queue !! why would i use BlockingCollection<T> if LOCK work fine ?? does it take alot of memory or something ?

Comment: Yes, like I said, every thread takes 1 MB of memory. That means if you copy 1000 files, you probably run out of memory. Also, `lock` does not guarantee any order, `BlockingCollection<T>` does.

Comment: can you edit your answer so i can see how to use BlockingCollection<T>